# Can I play sound from assets without Context in Android?

Tags: java, android, android-assets

For assets need to use getAssets() method, but this method requires the Context.

I found some interest method `getResourceAsStream()`.

Using:

```
private InputStream openFile(String filename) throws IOException {
   return getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(filename);
}
```

Next, how to convert InputStream to audio format?

Comment: `getResourceAsStream()` is not for either Android resources or assets. Beyond that, what do you mean by "convert InputStream to audio format"?

Comment: then for what? What are other ways to play sound without Context?

Comment: Whatever caused your code to run gave you a `Context`. Or your dependency inversion framework (Dagger, Koin, etc.) can give you a `Context`. Why is using a `Context` is a problem?

Comment: @CommonsWare, it's because it's not my app. I disassembled it using apktool. The Class where I want to play sound has no Context.